# Roots of the Tits form of a quiver algebra

Tags: reference-request, rt.representation-theory

Assume $A$ is a finite dimensional quiver algebra such that two indecomposable modules are isomorphic iff their dimension vectors are equal. It is known that $A$ is in this case representation-finite (at least when the field is algebraically closed, is this needed for quiver algebras?)

The tits quadratic form of $A$ is defined as in https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Tits_quadratic_form .

> Question: In case every dimension vector is a root of the tits form, is there automatically a bijection between the positive roots and the dimension vectors?

This seems to be true for Nakayama algebras.

The Nakayama algebra with Kupisch series [2,3,2,3] gives an example of a non-acyclic quiver algebra for this.